# Dash, is there any limitation on filepath

Tags: linux, shell, dash-shell

I have an executable which is placed on my Linux machine such that the length of the path to the executable is 107 characters. I found number of characters using command `echo -n "/path/to/the/executable" | wc -c -m`. When I try to execute the executable with its complete path I get the following error:

`sh: 1: /subpath/to/the/executable: not found`

I checked the length of `/subpath/to/the/executable` and it is 81 characters. And if I place my executable such that its path length is less than 81 characters, I don't get the above `sh error`.

I did some search and found that limit of file path on Linux env is 255 characters. I couldn't find if dash or shell has any limitation on the file path. On my machine /bin/sh is symbolic link to /bin/dash.

Can someone explain this limit of 81 characters on file path enforced by dash? Is there a way to increase the limit?

Comment: does `/subpath/` exist and correct? what is it, folder in / (root) or subfolder? (why you refer to it as a full path then?)

Comment: I suspect the actual paths involved are more relevant than their lengths.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk,  `/subpath/` doesn't exist. It is first 81 characters of `/path/to/the/executable `. Executable is placed inside various directories and I can change my current directory and execute the file as `./file` but I am executing it from java code and so I need to provide the complete path.

Comment: @chepner, in what sense? Can you explain a bit what you suspect?

Comment: I don't suspect anything in particular; I'm just not taking for granted that your assumption that 81 is a magic length is correct. What is the *actual* code that produces the error?

Comment: Show how you're executing the script. Is it with `sh /subpath/to/the/executable`, or are you using a `#!` line at the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `dash` (due to Linux) has limitations on the lengths of filepaths:

- No entry in the path can be longer than 255 characters.
- No total path can be longer than 4095 characters.

Here are examples demonstrating this:

```
$ "$(head -c 255 /dev/zero | tr '\0' 'x')"
dash: 2: xxxxxx[...]xxxxxxx: not found

$ "$(head -c 256 /dev/zero | tr '\0' 'x')"
dash: 3: xxxxxx[...]xxxxxxxx: File name too long

$ "$(while true; do printf "/x"; done | head -c 4095)"
dash: 4: /x/x/[...]/x/x/x/: not found

$ "$(while true; do printf "/x"; done | head -c 4096)"
dash: 5: /x/x/[...]/x/x/x/x: File name too long
```

No limit affects 81 character or 107 character names. Here's an example showing that 200 characters work just fine in `dash`:

```
$ name="./$(head -c 200 /dev/zero | tr '\0' x)"
$ printf '%s\n' '#!/bin/sh' 'echo "hello world"' > "$name"
$ chmod +x "$name"
$ "$name"
hello world
```

If you have any questions about why a Java program could fail to execute a command properly, please post them separately under the `java` tag. Make sure not to abbreviate or mask the filenames, since the exact values matter a lot.